# Resizing DIV to not cover the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have trouble with resizing divs by height. I have trouble that the bottom one covers the above one's content. I don't want it to cover it, I still want to be able to see all the content

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/radevska/8y4mLk6w/)`

```
var i = 0;
   $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){

        $('#mousestatus').html("mousedown" + i++);
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          $('#position').html(e.pageY +', '+ e.pageX);
          $('#sidebar').css("height",e.pageY-2);
          $('#main').css("top",e.pageY+12);
       })
       console.log("leaving mouseDown");
    });
   $(document).mouseup(function(e){
       $('#clickevent').html('in another mouseUp event' + i++);
       $(document).unbind('mousemove');
       });
```

`

Comment: #sidebar{
   background-color: red;
  height:100px;
 overflow-y:scroll; // or hidden to not overlap the content
} Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y4mLk6w/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/

Comment: That is the original code. The thing I want is the content to be affected by the change, not just cover it up. Better said the code to try to fit in the new size

Comment: For example when I try to resize, i want the button to go up, not hide ride away

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/radevska/djf5o4nx/